# Format seconds in mm:ss with moment

Tags: momentjs

I have to format a duration lets say `4000` seconds to `mm:ss` with `momentjs`.

what I have tried so far:

```
const duration = moment.duration(4000, 'seconds').asMilliseconds();
moment.utc(duration).format('mm:ss'); // output 06:40
```

the problem with this is as `4000sec is equal to 01:06:40` it's shows only the minutes and seconds and not append that 1 hours to minutes.

Comment: Add the hour format `moment.utc(duration).format('HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: are you not adding `HH` on purpose  in the format ? OR you expected that 1 hour to be converted to minutes as well ?

Comment: I want that 1 hr to be converted to minutes like 66:40 as 1 hr is 60 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `utc()` function at all since the `seconds` are always same. You can just use moment `duration` function and get minutes `asMinutes` and seconds as `.seconds()`

Also, asMinutes will return the `float` numbers as 66.66 so round it up use `Math.floor()`

**Working Demo:**

```js
const duration = moment.duration(4000, 'seconds')
const format = Math.floor(duration.asMinutes()) + ':' + duration.seconds()
console.log(format) //66:40
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Izh34nqeeR7/nwthfeE0SI3c8uhFSnqxV0sI9TvTcXiFJkMd6fB644O64BRq2P/LA/+7eRvCw4GmLsXksyTHBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: yeah that as the same solution I have come up with as I didn't find a native method in moment docs to do this. Btw, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini Thank heaps :) unfortunatly there is no native solution at all for what you are trying to achieve with momentJS library or even with native Javascript. Happy coding :)